# Alias on "_all" index not updated when new indices created

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a filtered alias in elasticsearch that I've created using "_all" as the index it is bound to. Like so:

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/_aliases" -d'
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "_all",
        "alias": "logs",
        "filter": { "type": { "value": "log" } }
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

I created this alias because the logs are being placed in different indices (by month actually), and I need to see the aggregate. **The problem I'm having is that whenever a new index is created, this alias is not updated**. The alias seems to only reference the indices that existed when the alias was created.

Is there a way to have the alias update when new indices are added? Or is there a better approach altogether to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need an index template, more about it [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

And here's an example, for your specific case:

```
PUT /_template/logs_template
{
  "template": "*",
  "aliases": {
    "logs": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "log"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above basically says that for each new index, whatever its name (`"*"`), associate the "logs" alias with it.